# locally installed font is not loading when using @font-face property

Tags: css, fonts

I tried to add a custom font using @font-face property. It works when I'm loading the downloaded Google font (`Raleway`) using the `url()` attribute. When I try to load the same font (`Raleway`) locally using `local()` attribute it loads only the `raleway-regular` font on all the @font-face versions(light,bold)

This is my code. This individual @font-face font works fine.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'raleway-regular';
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('raleway'),
  url('../fonts/raleway-regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('../fonts/raleway-regular.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/raleway-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('../fonts/raleway-regular.eot') format('embedded-opentype');
}
```

But when I try a to load the bolder version using below code the `local()` 
property does not load the locally installed bolder version of the font. The `url()` works fine. If I change the value of `local()` to local(`raleway`) it loads the font, but not the bolder version.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'raleway-black';
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  font-weight 900;
  src: local('raleway-black'),
  local ('raleway black'),
  url('../fonts/raleway-black.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('../fonts/raleway-black.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/raleway-black.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('../fonts/raleway-black.eot') format('embedded-opentype');
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure the name of the installed font is "Raleway Black" and not just "Raleway"? The error is with the `font-weight` property by the way, which is missing a colon.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MrLister .The colon is just a typing mistake. My bad. The installed font (Raleway) has several weights. So I'm trying to use the bolder version which is listed as "Raleway Black" next to the font name in fonts settings in windows. If i just use  local( 'Raleway')  it loads the regular weight of the font. what I'm trying to do here is , if the "Raleway" font is available locally then to load the relevant weight of it without loading the url() links.